# How to find all "feasible" values in an array in O(nlogn) and O(n)?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Suppose we are given a "black-box" which is a program procedure such that given any real
number x as the input, the procedure can tell whether x is a feasible value in constant time.
Further, we have the following basic rules: If x is a feasible value, then any number less
than x is also a feasible value; on the other hand, if x is not a feasible value, then any number
larger than x is not a feasible value.
Given an array A[1,..., n] of n real numbers, we want to find all feasible values of the
elements of A by using the black-box. For each element x of A, we can call the black-box on
x to determine whether x is feasible value. In this way, by calling the black-box n times, we can find all feasible values of A in O(n) time. However, by making use of the above basic
rules, it is possible to find all feasible values of A by calling the black-box significantly less
than n times. For simplicity, we assume that no two numbers of A are equal.

1) first I want to design an O(n log n) time algorithm to find all feasible values of A by calling the black-
box at most O(log n) times.

2) then I want to improve my algorithm to O(n) time such that the total number of calls on the black-
box is still at most O(log n).

So far I have designed an algorithim inspired by the prune and search algorithm and selection:

```
findFeasible(A, blackBox)
{
randomly pick an element of A as the pivot (p);
A1: the set of elements < p;
A2: the set of elemetns > p;
out = blackBox(p);
if out == feasible
         return p, A1;
         findFeasible(A2, blackBox);
if out != feasible
         findFeasible(A1, blackBox);
```

But I'm not sure what is the timing for this algorithm I wrote and what could be done to improve.

Comment: Yes I am sure this is possible, and No there is no more information about the task, this is all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 2)

Find the median of the array in O(n) using [quickselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect). Check if the median is feasible. If it is, run the algorithm recursively on the left half of the array. If it is not, run the algorithm in the right side.

Each time you run the quickselect, you divide the length by 2. So, the total cost will be

O(n) + O(n/2) + O(n/4) + O(n/8) ... = O(n)

performing O(log n) calls to the blackbox.

Comment: I think this is very close, but unfortunately not quite correct as it stands: If you are unluncky, at each step you get the next smallest/largest element as pivot. Then you actually run in O(n^2). However, there is a variation of quickselect which can be used. See median of medians: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians. Also, a detail, but usually we sort from low to high. So if the element you find is feasible, you should recurse on the right half, not the left one...but yes, of course it also works the other way around - its just a bit odd. Other than that: this is rly cool!

Comment: @dingalapadum Yes, you are right. I said quickselect is O(n) in the same sense people usually say quicksort is O(n log n) or that hash table lookup is O(1). It isn't quite so, and in both quicksort and quickselect a simple change in the partition scheme can achieve optimal complexities.

Answer (score 1):

For 1):

Sort the array in O(n*log(n)) time.
Then do a binary-search to find the index of the element which splits the array into the lower part (feasible values) and upper part (not feasible values). Binary-search will take O(log(n)).